# How to scan complex numbers in java

Tags: java

How can i scan number inserted in this form: 1.7+2.8990i in java? I imagine its possible to split the line one time with +, or -? How should i take this line as a string or sth else?

Thanks

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/complex.html

Comment: Have you experimented with writing your own parser? If so, can you please show what you've tried with comments as to why it's not working? Edit, I like @JasonSperske's possible solution.

Comment: i have this so far: 
                String operator = null;
  String Podatki[];
  while (operator != "izhod"){
   //preberemo operator
   System.out.print("Vtipkaj ukaz (+, -, *, /, w): ");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
   operator = scan.nextLine();
   //preberemo stevili
   Podatki = new String[2];
   for (int i = 0; i < Podatki.length; i++){
           System.out.print("vnesi kompleksno stevilo ");
           Podatki[i] = scan.nextLine();
           System.out.println();
           System.out.println(Podatki[i]);
   }

And i would like to split it using . + - and i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to use a library there is always [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/index.html) which lets you do stuff like this:

```
ComplexFormat cf = new ComplexFormat();
Complex c = cf.parse("1.110 + 2.222i");
Complex second = new Complex(2.0, 5.0);
Complex answer = c.log();        // natural logarithm.
        answer = c.cos();        // cosine
        answer = c.pow(second);  // first raised to the power of second

ComplexFormat format = new ComplexFormat(); // default format
String s1 = format.format(c);      // s1 contains "1.110 + 2.222i"
String s2 = format.format(second); // s2 contains "2.0 + 5.0i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a RegEx approach (without external library but also without ability to use a Complex Number for more than just parsing):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)i",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1.7+2.8990i");
if(matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println("a:" + Float.parseFloat(matcher.group(1)));
  System.out.println("b:" + Float.parseFloat(matcher.group(2)));
} else {
  System.out.println("Not a complex number");
}
```

This approach supports positive and negative values for a and b.  Now one weaknesses to this approach are it doesn't tolerate spaces around number (you could safely strip spaces from your input and not alter the equation).